# How to move headers from the top to the bottom of the page and insert a logo at the right top of each document page?

Tags: graphics, header-footer

I am using the code below to develop a course syllabus. I tried different approaches without success to add an [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bras%C3%A3o_da_UFPE.png) at the top right of each document page and simultaneously move the header that appears on the second page to the bottom of the document's pages.

```
\documentclass[PS,11pt]{syllabus}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[small,compact]{titlesec} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Reduce spacing between itemize
\let\tempone\itemize
\let\temptwo\enditemize
\renewenvironment{itemize}{\tempone\addtolength{\itemsep}{-.5\baselineskip}}{\temptwo}

% Roman section numbers
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 

\usepackage[pdftex, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksnumbered=true, 
pdfstartview=FitH, breaklinks=true, urlbordercolor={0 1 1}, citebordercolor={0 1 0}, colorlinks = true]{hyperref}

% To eliminate the newline after \subsubsection
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{}{}{}{}[]

% Shade within enumerate
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\newmdenv[backgroundcolor=gray!40,roundcorner=10pt,nobreak=true]{shaded}

% Dot after section number
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}

\textheight 9in
\textwidth 6.5in
\topmargin -.5in
\oddsidemargin 0in
\evensidemargin 0in

\newcommand{\percent}{\ensuremath{\%\;}}


\begin{document}

\title{\textbf{Course Title} \\ 
\vspace{.2cm}
Syllabus}
\name{Professor\\
    \vspace{.2cm}Year}


\businessAddress{\emph{Room}: TBD \\ \emph{Time}: Tuesday/Thursday 
5:00-6:20pm\\
\emph{Prerequisites}: None

}

\homeAddress{
             \emph{Email}: 
             \href{mailto:professor@univ.edu}{\color{gray}{professor@univ.edu}}\\
             \emph{Office Hour}: Thu 11:00am-Noom, sign up 
             \href{TBD}{\color{gray}{online}},\\
\hspace{2.5cm}Room: 
TBD, or by appointment.\\
\textbf{TA}: TBD\\
             \emph{Email}: 
             \href{mailto:tbd}{\color{gray}{tbd}}\\
             \emph{Office Hour}: TBD, Room: TBD \\ 
\hspace{2.5cm}or by appointment. \\
             }


\begin{syllabus}

\textbf{{\Large Overview and Course Goals}}\\

\vspace{-.2cm}

\lipsum[3-5]

\pagebreak

\lipsum[3-5]

\end{syllabus}
\end{document}
```

[image: Page one]

[image: Page two]

Comment: In LaTeX, you generally add headers and footers via the `fancyhdr` package.

Comment: What is your `syllabus` class?

Comment: You can add pagestyles the old fashion way using `\def\ps@mystyle{...}`.  See the document class source for esamples.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum I do not know. I just use the code above to generate the document. Any suggestions on how I can check the `syllabus` class?

Answer (score 0):

After several additional tries, I got it! It is probably possible to have a better code, but it does the task.

```
\documentclass[PS,11pt]{syllabus}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[small,compact]{titlesec} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Added this package
\usepackage{graphicx} % Added this package
\usepackage[margin=1in,
headheight=25pt,                           
]{geometry}

% Reduce spacing between itemize
\let\tempone\itemize
\let\temptwo\enditemize
\renewenvironment{itemize}{\tempone\addtolength{\itemsep}{-.5\baselineskip}}{\temptwo}

% Roman section numbers
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 

\usepackage[pdftex, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksnumbered=true, 
pdfstartview=FitH, breaklinks=true, urlbordercolor={0 1 1}, citebordercolor={0 
    1 0}, colorlinks = true]{hyperref}

% To eliminate the newline after \subsubsection
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{}{}{}{}[]

% Shade within enumerate
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\newmdenv[backgroundcolor=gray!40,roundcorner=10pt,nobreak=true]{shaded}

% Dot after section number
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}

\textheight 9in
\textwidth 6.5in
\topmargin -.5in
\oddsidemargin 0in
\evensidemargin 0in

\newcommand{\percent}{\ensuremath{\%\;}}

% Header and Footer configuration
\fancypagestyle{syllabusstyle}{
    \fancyhf{} % Clear all header and footer fields
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{logo_ufpe.png}}
    %%% % Added image to the header
    \fancyfoot[L]{\emph{Professor}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\emph{Quarter}}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage} % Added page number in the right footer
}
\pagestyle{syllabusstyle}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{} % Clear all header and footer fields
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{logo_ufpe.png}} % 
    %Added image to the header
    \fancyfoot[L]{\emph{Professor}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\emph{Quarter}}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage} % Added page number in the right footer
}

\fancypagestyle{firststyle}
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \rhead{\raisebox{-2.2\height}{\includegraphics[height=30mm]{logo_ufpe.png}}}
}

\usepackage{graphicx,eso-pic}
% lipsum provides:   \lipsum
% mwe provides:      example-image
% graphicx provides: \includegraphics
% eso-pic provides:  \AddTo..., \AtStockUpperLeft

\newlength\headpicwd
\newlength\headpicht
\setlength{\headpicwd}{10mm}% image width of physical page?
\setlength{\headpicht}{1.7cm}
\newcommand\printpic{%
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
        \AtStockUpperLeft{%
            \raisebox{-\headpicht}{%
                % centred with respect to physical page ..?
                \hspace*{\dimexpr 0.73\pdfpagewidth - 0.5\headpicwd\relax}%
                \includegraphics[width=\headpicwd, 
                height=\headpicht]{logo_ufpe.png}%
            }%
        }%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
    % print logo
    \printpic
    
    \title{\textbf{Course Title} \\ 
        \vspace{.2cm}
        Syllabus}
    \name{Professor\\
        \vspace{.2cm}Year}
    
    
    \businessAddress{\emph{Room}: TBD \\ \emph{Time}: Tuesday/Thursday 
        5:00-6:20pm\\
        \emph{Prerequisites}: None
    }
    
    \homeAddress{
        \emph{Email}: 
        \href{mailto:professor@univ.edu}{\color{gray}{professor@univ.edu}}\\
        \emph{Office Hour}: Thu 11:00am-Noon, sign up 
        \href{TBD}{\color{gray}{online}},\\
        \hspace{2.5cm}Room:
        TBD, or by appointment.\\
        \textbf{TA}: TBD\\
        \emph{Email}:
        \href{mailto:tbd}{\color{gray}{tbd}}\\
        \emph{Office Hour}: TBD, Room: TBD \\ 
        \hspace{2.5cm} or by appointment. \\
    }
    
    %\thispagestyle{firststyle}
    
    \begin{syllabus}
        
        \textbf{{\Large Overview and Course Goals}}\\
        
        \vspace{-.2cm}
        
        \lipsum[3-5]
        
        \pagebreak
        
        \lipsum[3-5]
        
        \pagebreak
        
        \lipsum[3-5]
        
    \end{syllabus}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You are on the right track. If `fancyhdr` cannot do it, then it probably requires much more arcane code. Now, there may be some pages where you do not want the image or footer to appear, or wish to change the content. That can also be done with `fancyhdr`. Its documentation tells you how.